# Who created the difference between Thenkalai and Vadakalai sects?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, vadakalai, thenkalai

Actually I am very curious to know who created the difference between Thenkalai and Vadakalai sects of Sri Vaishnava Sampradaya?

Comment: Are you asking who actually separated the two sects or just which figures were responsible for the philosophical differences that ultimately led to the split?  Because as far as I know, it's unknown who actually created the split, just that it must have happened centuries after the underlying philosophical differences emerged.